# Use Google Cloud Build to deploy Firebase without Firebase CI token

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-build

In my `package.json` I have this line:

```
{
  "deploy:ci": firebase deploy --force --only functions --token \"$SECRET\"
}
```

And my `cloudbuild.yaml`:

```
steps:
  - name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker"
    args: ["build", "--tag", "gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/functions", "."]

  - name: "gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/functions"
    args: ["yarn", "deploy:ci"]
    secretEnv: ["FIREBASE_TOKEN"]

secrets:
  - kmsKeyName: projects/myproject/locations/global/keyRings/enviroment/cryptoKeys/firebase
    secretEnv:
      FIREBASE_TOKEN: VERY_LONG_UNGLY_AND_BORING_BASE64_STRING
```

I want to know if it is possible to add some "special" permissions to the cloudbuild in order to allow the deployment without this `FIREBASE_TOKEN`.

(all files are in the same project)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, it is possible. But there are couple of stuff you need to do

assuming your cloud build looks like this

```
steps:
  - name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm"
    args: ["install"]

  - name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm"
    args: ["run", "build]

  - name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/firebase"
    args: ["deploy"]
```

You need to upload your own `firebase` image from [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders-community/tree/master/firebase), I assume you are already familiar with this, otherwise, I wrote basically a similar post about how to do this part [here](https://thecloudfunction.com/blog/firebase-cloud-functions-continuous-deploying-with-cloud-build/) anyway...

After that, the IAM you are asking for is `Firebase Admin`, you need to assign this to your `...@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com` account.

Voila! you can test it like (using the sdk)

```
gcloud builds submit --config cloudbuild.yaml .
```

Of course point to your file location.

**Opinionated comment**: I'm not a big fan of this approach, I tried a few times and there were always some issues with it, but well, that's why we called it `opinionated comment` :)

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks @andresmijares, and I agree with you.